# Base64 encode is becoming a piece of the image

Tags: android, image, bitmap, base64

I'm trying to get an image from the Gallery and send it to a server.
I do get an base64 encoded string but it's a thin line, not the whole image.

For example, I used Motobit to decode [this random image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvCn6.jpg) The base64 string I got 
works fine. But the encoded string that I get from my app for the same image is really smaller and when you convert into an image it becomes [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgT7X.png)

Here is my code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_profile);


    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                try {
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

                    String imageStream = getRealPathFromURI(context, selectedImage);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageStream);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
                    String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, encodedString);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

What is making my `encodedString` becomes only a piece of the image? Thanks!

Comment: You are not showing how you decode your encodedString. So how could we comment on where things go wrong? And where does this go wrong? You did not tell. You should tell sizes of byte arrays and length of strings. Smaller? Be exact.

Comment: @greednapps I'm decoding in this website: http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Comment: @greenapps Because when I send this way to the server it goes as a corrupted image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the string is correct but the Log method has a character limit.